# render partial view from a grid selection in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, partial, telerik-mvc

I have a telerik grid in an MVC 3 Razor project.  Next to the grid is a partial view that uses an appropriate model template.  How would I go about using the onRowSelect to render the partial view with the index from the row selected.  Essentially its calling a javascript, in the java script it specifies the index int I want to pass to the partial view.  However, I am unable to render the partial view with the new index. 
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the ajax update targetID

Answer (score 0):

Have you tri[client selection](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/selectionclientside?theme=vista) in telerik demo page